# Sending SOAP requests with PHP using a certificate file

Tags: php, soap, certificate

I have to use SOAP on a certain server with php and the client has provided me with a server.keystore, in what seem to be in PKCS12 format and i have been trying to connect to it and use it. The problem is no matter what i do i always get "Could not connect to host" error. The keystore file contains an intermcacert, rootcacert and PrivateKeyEntry, i have tried converting it to pem to use in PHPs SoapClient (with or without a password), i have tried converting it to a key and crt file, still no luck, no luck. I have no more ideas on what to do. here is the php i use

```
$options =[
    

    'trace'=>true,
    'keep_alive' => false,
    'local_cert'    => $pathTotheFile,
    'passphrase'    => $passphrase,
    
    // 
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    // 
    'location'=> 'https://the_url',
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ],  
    ]),

];


try {
$soapclient = new SoapClient($path, $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}


try{
$soapclient->someFunction();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
     exit;
}
```

but always get the same error "Could not connect to host". At the same time everything works in SOAP UI, with the same keystore and password.
Every suggestion is most welcome